# How to find complexity of Haskell code

Tags: haskell, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am new to analysis of algorithms. I have a fair understanding of functional languages. I would like to know how to calculate **time and space** complexity of a given Haskell program.

eg.

```
innerProduct :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a
innerProduct x y = sum (zipWith (*) x y)
```

I need a step by step analysis so that I can understand better.

Thanks.

Comment: There's not much step-by-step to be done here – this function simply has the max complexity of `sum` and `zipWith`. Both are _O_ (_n_) in space and time (`zipWith` only if you actually force the entire result, but `sum` does this anyway).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ok, suppose I have another function that uses innerProduct as: matrixMult xs ys = [ [ ( innerProduct x y ) | x <- xs ] | y <- transpose ys ], the complexity will be O(n)

Comment: nothing precludes a clever implementation from fusing `sum` and `zipWith (*)` into one O(1)-space loop (as  described  by Daniel P. Friedman and David S. Wise in 1974 TR19: "Unwinding Structured Recursions into Iterations"). Haskell the *language* doesn't say one way or the other.

Comment: There cannot be a general step-by-step analysis that assesses complexity, because even deciding termination is not possible, for bounded recursion of course, but in general no, so be a bit more specific about what classes of programs you care about.